# What is best way to run karate when tests are not part of a java project, but do include some test logic written in java?

Tags: java, dependencies, karate

My karate tests are not part of a java project.  I run them against an externally deployed java micro-service (derived from the jvm property I called `serviceName`).  I do so with a command like this:

```
java -Dkarate.env=qa -DserviceName=aca-retention -cp './karate.jar:.' com.intuit.karate.Main --tags @tier1 --threads 3 .
```

The .feature files are in and beneath the current working directory.
The classpath includes the current working dir, because that's where i compiled a custom java class that I use to [mask stuff in the logs](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#log-masking). This has worked fine.

Now, I have a need to implement some test logic in java code, so I have another java class to compile, and it depends on the aws sdk.
But, I can't figure out how to make my class work when I try to invoke it via [karate's ability to call java](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#calling-java).

I tried making a stand-alone spring-boot project that includes my one custom java class and the aws sdk dependencies.  But, when i try to call it from a karate feature, I get
an error like this:

```
12:54:59.939 tier2/aca-retention/fixed-retention.feature:39
* def S3ObjectRetention = Java.type('com.nm.aca.test.S3ObjectRetention')
js failed:
>>>>
01: Java.type('com.nm.aca.test.S3ObjectRetention')
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: Access to host class com.nm.aca.test.S3ObjectRetention is not allowed or does not exist.
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)

tier2/aca-retention/fixed-retention.feature:39
```

Line 39 looks like this:

```
* def S3ObjectRetention = Java.type('com.nm.aca.test.S3ObjectRetention')
```

I also tried compiling my custom java class by itself, and including the aws sdk jars via the classpath, but when i run karate, it fails with an error like this:

```
* def retainUntil = S3ObjectRetention.get(s3BucketName, s3ObjectKey)
js failed:
>>>>
01: S3ObjectRetention.get(s3BucketName, s3ObjectKey)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client
- S3ObjectRetention.get(S3ObjectRetention.java:9)
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)

tier2/aca-retention/fixed-retention.feature:40
```

where lines 39&40 of the feature file are like this:

```
* def S3ObjectRetention = Java.type('S3ObjectRetention')
* def retainUntil = S3ObjectRetention.get(s3BucketName, s3ObjectKey)
```

and line 9 of the java file is the first line of java that tries to use an aws sdk class:

```
S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder()
                                    .region(Region.US_EAST_1) // Specify your desired AWS region
                                    .build();
```

Anyone know what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Should I try using maven to run my karate tests instead of the java command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like classpath issues, refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/develop/karate-netty#custom-classpath

This is not a typical use of Karate so I suggest you try other options such as Maven, or work with someone who knows Java well. Hard to diagnose this without a way to replicate.

Comment: Agreed it sounds like a classpath problem. I'll try using maven instead.

I created a maven project using [the archetype:generate](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#how-do-i-make-my-first-maven-project) goal, moved my java code to src/main/java/{groupId}, and my feature files to src/test/java/{groupId}.  Recall that my java code is only used by karate.

How can I run karate from the mvn command-line, and without depending on JUnit?  I need to provide java properties, karate tags, thread-count (for parallel runner), and a directory path to feature files.

Comment: I tried:

`mvn test -D"karate.options=--tags @qa --threads 3 ." -Dkarate.env=qa -DserviceName=aca-acme`

but it did not run karate.